# Not able to resolve issue(HTTP error 404) with seaborn.load_dataset function

Tags: python, seaborn, amazon-sns

I used below code to use a dataset from my own github account(Disclaimer: Dataset used from some other location & name modified to keep in my github account).
    import seaborn as sns

```
df = sns.load_dataset('https://github.com/vishalkrsinha/Python/blob/Data/FiveYearData.csv')
```

But, it gives me the error as below(Traceback). I understand load_dataset() function looks for online dataset. I also tried using physical path (as online path was giving error) but could not succeed. Kindly suggest the solution.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/DataVisualization/Test.py", line 10, in 
    df = sns.load_dataset('https://github.com/vishalkrsinha/Python/blob/Data/FiveYearData.csv')
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 428, in load_dataset
    urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It could be a duplicate question, but I m still looking for the solution. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Got the solution by debugging. Short explanation:
The second parameter of load_dataset() is 'cache' that has default boolean value as 'True'. So, if dataset not found online then the function looks into below physical path: 
 C:\Users\user1\seaborn-data
This path should have your dataset if not found online:
 df = sns.load_dataset('FiveYearData') 
We can also provide different physical path for dataset through third parameter (data_home) as below:
 df = sns.load_dataset('FiveYearData',data_home=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("FiveYearData")))